# AngularJS ng-repeat ignores filter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use a filter with ng-repeat. 
Unfortunately it seems to ignore the result of the function which is attached to the filter.

HTML:

```
<a ng-repeat="item in date track by $index | filter: filterFunction('2015-09-23',item)" class="item item-icon-left" >
      <div class="listcontent">{{title[$index]}}
          <br> <span class="subinfo">{{item}}</span>
      </div>   
     <i class="iconarrowmore ion-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filterFunction = function (datestamp, element) {
    if (datestamp == element) {
        console.log(datestamp == element);
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log(datestamp == element);
        return false;
    }
};
```

It returns either true or false when I debug it with console.log but every item still appears in the list.

[image]

I really have no clue why its doing that.

Comment: Doesn't it just skip the item if the filter returns false?
It makes it easier that way

Answer (score 1):

Your filtering function is `undefined`. Note, that with `filter: filterFunction('2015-09-23',item)` you immediately execute `filterFunction` and use its result as filter, which is `undefined` because your function doesn't return anything.

To fix it make `filterFunction` return new filter function:

```
$scope.filterFunction = function(datestamp) {
    return function(element) {
        return datestamp == element;
    };
};
```

Then HTML part will be the same just you don't need to pass item:

```
ng-repeat="item in date track by $index | filter: filterFunction('2015-09-23')"
```

See it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/jLQbgGcLSAxwmiCcYZdP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks!! Your code is working with the example but if I add the same date to that list again and then add track by $index to the ng-repeat it stops working.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the solution.

If one is using "track by index" with a filter one has to but that behind the filter:

```
ng-repeat="item in date | filter: filterFunction('2015-09-23') track by $index"
```

I hope that helps someone.

Cheers, 
Valentin